# How can I compute a random value with multimodal distribution?

Tags: random, vhdl, normal-distribution

I would like to compute a random value with a multimodal distribution composed of `N` normal distributions.

I have an array with `N` elements of normal distribution parameters (std deviation, mean).

My language (VHDL) and my library allow me to calculate the following basic distributions:
  - uniform distribution [-1.0; 1.0]
  - normal distribution (Box Muller transformation)
  - Poisson distribution

How can I calculate random values so that the histogram looks like `N` overlapping normal distributions?

[image: two normal distributions]

Types and helpers:

```
type T_NORMAL_DIST_PARAM is record
    StdDev : REAL;
    Mean   : REAL;
  end record;
  type T_JITTER_DIST is array(NATURAL range <>) of T_NORMAL_DIST_PARAM;
  constant JitterDistribution : T_JITTER_DIST := (
    0 => (0.2, -0.4),
    1 => (0.2,  0.4)
  );
```

The problems core:

```
procedure getMultiModalDistributedRandomNumber(Seed : T_SIM_SEED; Value : REAL; JitterDistribution : T_JITTER_DIST) is
  variable rand   : REAL;
  variable Result : REAL;
begin
  -- ...
  for i in JitterDistribution'range loop
    getNormalDistributedRandomValue(Seed, rand, JitterDistribution(i).StdDev,  JitterDistribution(i).Mean);
    -- how to accumulate rand?
  end loop;
  Value := Result;
end procedure;
```

It's used in:

```
procedure genClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; Period : TIME) is
  constant TimeHigh : TIME := Period / 2;
  constant TimeLow : TIME := Period - TimeHigh;
  variable rand : REAL;
begin
  initializeSeed(Seed);
  while (not isStopped) loop
    getMultiModalDistributedRandomNumber(Seed, rand, JitterDistribution);
    Clock <= '1';
    wait for TimeHigh + (Period * rand);
    Clock <= '0';
    wait for TimeLow;
  end loop;
end procedure;
```

Comment: Use the uniform distribution to generate an integer and use that integer to select which of the N parameter sets to use to generate a normal.

Comment: This solution is to easy :).

Comment: As @pjs said, compute relative weights of gaussian by using areas under the curves, use U(0,1) to sample from weights index of particular gaussian, and then call your normal distributions. Easy...

Comment: @Paebbels Are VHDL arrays 0- or 1-based?

Comment: They can be based anywhere :), but most arrays are zero based except for string, it's one based. I scaled the random value to 10 times N and used mod N afterwards. This should reduce rounding effects at the boundardies. The measured histogram looks as expected. I think I can post the complete code snippet tomorrow.

Comment: VHDL arrays are 0 or 1 or anything you want based. Declare whatever lower bound makes sense for your problem.

Comment: Congrats, glad that works for you.

Comment: Are you still going to post the snippet or what? that way we an close this question.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius What snippet? If you have a question then ask it in a polite way! I won't post a users comment as my answer and collect his credits. That's not how SO works.

Comment: "I think I can post the complete code snippet tomorrow. – Paebbels Jan 25 '16 at 1:34". You wil not get credits for answering your own question. And just properly cite your sources.

Comment: This question appears in the unanswered list, but it seems it is already answered. Questions should not be answered in the comments: that's not how stackoverflow is supposed to work. It has nothing to do with credits!